# Python syntax. Beautiful, right, short code

Tags: python, iteration

```
for item in listOfModels:
    if item[0] in perms:
        perms[item[0]][item[1]] = True
    else:
        perms[item[0]] = {item[1]: True}
```

I often use code like this. Please tell me beautiful, short, right way to do same.

(lib's, books, samples, etc.)

E.G. 
i have

```
[
    ['animal', 'rabbit'],
    ['animal', 'cow'],
    ['plant', 'tree'],
    ['animal', 'elephant'],
    ['fruit', 'strawberry'],
    ['fruit', 'apple'],
]
```

and need

```
{
    'animal': ['rabbit', 'cow', 'elephant'],
    'plant': ['tree'],
    'fruit': ['strawberry', 'apple'],
}
```

OR

```
{
'animal': {
    'rabbit': True,
    'cow': True,
    'elephant': True
},
'plant': {
    'tree': True
},
'fruit': {
    'strawberry': True,
    'apple': True
},
```

Comment: `for key1, key2 in listOfModels: perms.setdefault(key1, {})[key2] = True` - see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two options: use [`dict.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) or use a [`collections.defaultdict()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Using `dict.setdefault()`:

```
for category, name in listOfModels:
    perms.setdefault(category, {})[name] = True
```

or using a `defaultdict`:

```
from collection import defaultdict

perms = defaultdict(dict)
for category, name in listOfModels:
    perms[category][name] = True
```

`dict.setdefault()` looks up the key for you, and if it is missing uses the second argument to set the value. That way you *always* get a dictionary back (even an empty one), on which you can then set the `name` key.

A `defaultdict` takes a factory argument, and each time a key you try to access is missing, the factory is called to produce a default value. So accessing `perms['missing_key']` has the same effect as using `perms.set_default('missing_key', default)`; a new value is produced as needed.

Either method is trivially adapted to produce lists or sets instead of a dictionary with `True` values:

```
# producing a list
for category, name in listOfModels:
    perms.setdefault(category, []).append(name)

# or a set
for category, name in listOfModels:
    perms.setdefault(category, set()).append(name)

# same with defaultdict
perms = defaultdict(list)
for category, name in listOfModels:
    perms[category].append(name)

perms = defaultdict(set)
for category, name in listOfModels:
    perms[category].add(name)
```

Sets are probably the best option here, being the direct equivalent of the dictionary with values set to `True`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `setdefault` method.

```
for item in listOfModels:
    perms.setdefault(item[0], {})[item[1]] = True
```

If you know that each item has exactly two elements, you can shorten it further to

```
for item0, item1 in listOfModels:
    perms.setdefault(item0, {})[item1] = True
```

If you want to go crazy with `itertools`:

```
import operator, itertools
first = operator.itemgetter(0)
second = operator.itemgetter(1)
grouped = itertools.groupby(sorted(listOfModels, key=first), key=first)
result = dict((kind, map(second, examples)) for kind, examples in grouped)
```